# User locked via ActiveSync

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync, nokia

We have some user in our company is constantly locked in the Active Directory via ActiveSync.
We are reading logs and doing various tests. We was found out:

1. We see logon attempts with the wrong password from IP of mobile operator.
2. Phone brand is Nokia.
3. Phone isn't listed in partnership list of Exchange ActiveSync. Maybe it was there, but we clean the entire list, when try to resolve the problem.
4. We know a phone ID, but it's impossible to block.
5. We don't know the location of the phone.

What else can we do to resolve this problem?

We can't just turn off ActiveSync, because user have another phone synchronized.

Comment: Block the IP instead of the user ? (If that's possible - I don't know much about Activesync)

Comment: Impossible. In logs we see, that the IP frequently changes.

Comment: You could try changing the username of the user.

Comment: I know. But isn't a good solution. I think, should be a way to do this via Exchange.

Comment: @KonstantinBratulin Can you post the output of: `Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox <UserName> | Select *`?

Comment: `RunspaceId              : db447de1-6cb0-4e7f-8329-4349645f174d
FriendlyName            : Nexus 5
DeviceId                : android1415967835201
DeviceImei              : 352136064472596
DeviceMobileOperator    : ORANGE (42501)
DeviceOS                : Android 5.0.1
DeviceOSLanguage        :
DeviceTelephoneNumber   :
DeviceType              : Android
DeviceUserAgent         : Android/5.0.1-EAS-2.0
DeviceModel             : Nexus 5
FirstSyncTime           : 12/30/2014 7:26:56 AM...`

Comment: @EliadTech User have only one ActiveSync device-Nexus5.   We run `Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -mailbox user | Select-Object Identity | Remove-ActiveSyncDevice`   End re-add nexus. But it's not a problem device. We power off nexus and after this see lockouts.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might be able to do a specific filter with a firewall rule, but that would probably require SSL inspection which could prove quite a headache.
2. Here's an option to block ActiveSync devices (through ECP), but as far as I can tell there's no way to block a specific device, but a type.
   http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/11/15/3411539.aspx
3. You can try contact the mobile operator, and ask their help.

If the options above have failed (or just irrelevant), then I'd go with AWippler suggestion and change the username - it's the simplest and surest option.

EDIT:
I've just [found a blog](http://port25guy.com/2010/06/25/how-to-lock-down-activesync-users-to-specific-device-in-exchange-2010-or-exchange-2007/) that demonstrates how to block specific device by ID, but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: 1.  We check this option.Impossible.  2.  How can I block type of devices in ECP?  3.  We try. They can't help.

Comment: @KonstantinBratulin Edited my post. Added a link that explains how to use the ECP. But I've also found a blog that might solve this problem...

Comment: `Set-CasMailbox user –ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs` Did not help. I will continue search the solution in ECP preferences.